# VS2012 C++ DLL compatability

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp, visual-studio-2012

I have a DLL compiled in vs10 on windows xp 32bit
Then i moved to windows 7 32bit and compiled it in vs2012, the project build target was win32.
The new compiled DLL works perfectly when i use it on windows 7, but when i run it on win xp sp3 it says the program cant find the dll error
0x8007007E

How is that possible and what settings do I have to change?

Comment: Could you try `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`?

Comment: Use depends.exe. 0x8007007E is ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND. See some tips in http://flashexperiments.insh-allah.com/ApacheError126.html

Comment: VS2012 RTM does not support creating C++ executables that can run on XP.  That's being worked on, keep an eye on the C++ team blog for updates.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to static-link the runtime modules using /MT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx